# Passing an array parameter to a function mantain current pointer in PHP5.5?

Tags: php, arrays, pointers

I'm learning for ZCPE and in StudyGuide is the next quote:

`passing an array in as a function argument, unless you
pass-by-reference using the & operator, a copy is passed and the internal pointer is
always set to the first position, making a call to reset() unnecessary`

So i made a test:

```
function test($arr) {
    echo current($arr);
}

$arr = array('a','b','c');

next($arr); next($arr);

test($arr);
```

The output in `test()` function is `c`, which means that array argument was sent obvious as a copy but with internal pointer cloned at the same position as array from global space.

The documentation is for PHP5.3 but i cannot find such a change in `PHP Manual`.

Maybe is a bug, but i'm not sure because i did not find information in manual for how the pointer it's maintained when passing an array argument to a function.

Any information for this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose to pass parameter by referance or by copy, example: 
**Exemple 1**

```
function fn($a) {
// some job
}

$a = 5;
fn(&$a); // i choose to pass variable a by referance, instead of my declaration
```

Exemple 2

```
function fn(&$a) {
// some job
}
fn($a); // will be passed by referance, whatever i do ...
fb(&$a) ; // also by referance : WARNING this has been removed from the new version of PHP !
```

in the offical documentation in php, they are mentioned that the parameter of `next()` will be automaically passed by referance:

```
mixed next ( array &$array )
```

So it is not a bug :) 
Hope that Helps

Comment: You misinterpreted my question. I know the behaviour that you describe. The question was about the correctness of the quote from StudyGuide. They say that when passing an array agument to a function the internal pointer of the copy array is always at the begining, and from my test this is not the case, the pointer position is mantained, so a reset() call is necessary if i want to iterate through each, while ...